# This is a valid C code but not a valid C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

In some library I'm using (written in C) its

```
StorePGM(image, width, height, filename)
char *image;
int width, height;
char *filename;
{
  // something something
}
```

All functions are defined this way. I never seen such function definitions in my life. They seem to be valid to MSVC but when I compile it as C++ it gives errors.

What is it? some kind of old version C?

Comment: You shouldn't arbitrarily compile C code as C++.  If you need to use it with C++ code, you can link the code together and tell your C++ code to use C-linkage (`extern "C"`).

Comment: I remember seeing this syntax for the first time, about 1982. I thought it was the bee's knees! (After FORTRAN, a lot of things look like the bee's knees.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. K&R, pre-standard C. Avoid using it.

Comment: Yes, and they also suggest not using it in new project since the third edition of the book.

Comment: @Alex - The third edition of K&R's "The C Programming Language", the bible for C programmers.

Comment: From back in the goo old days, when the entire language could be adequately explained in about 100 pages (a least in the first edition).

Comment: It's still standard; both C90 and C99 still support old-style function definitions, and even the latest C201X draft hasn't removed them.  Personally, I consider this unfortunate.  (Note that I'm not disagreeing; it *is* pre-standard, it just also happens to be standard.)

Answer (score 5):

Before the 1989 ANSI C standard, C didn't have prototypes (function declarations that specify the types of the parameters); these old-style declarations and definitions were all that was available.

In 1989, the ANSI C standard (which essentially became the 1990 ISO C standard) introduced prototypes.  If I recall correctly, the idea actually came from C++ (which had not yet been standardized at the time).  Old-style declarations and definitions remained legal, so that old code could still be compiled.  The 1989 standard also said that old-style declarations were "obsolescent", meaning that they could be removed in a future version of the standard.

The 1999 ISO C standard, which (officially) superseded the 1990 standard, left this alone; old-style declarations and definitions are still legal, and all conforming compilers must support them (though they're free to warn about them, as they can warn about anything else).

As of the [latest C201X draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (large PDF), this *still* hasn't changed.  Old-style function declarations and definitions are still a required part of the language, and all conforming compilers must support them.  (Personally, I consider this unfortunate.)

C++, on the other hand, has never (?) supported anything other than prototypes as function declarations; Stroustrup wasn't as concerned about maintaining compatibility with old C code.

But unless you need to maintain very old code and/or use very old compilers, there is no good reason to use old-style function declarations or definitions.

Note that, at least in C, this definition:

```
int main() {
    /* ... */
}
```

is actually an old-style definition.  It's correct for C++, where it's a prototype indicating that `main` has no parameters, but in C it should be

```
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

(C++ also accepts this form for compatibility with C -- but by the time you're writing `main`, you should already have decided which language you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's K&R-Style.  (Kernighan & Ritchie are the inventors of C) See also http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-tutor.html for examples of this pre-ANSI style.

Comment: Kernighan had nothing to do with the invention of C.