# JNI Bindings - Undefined symbol: gcj_personality_v0

Tags: java, c++, binding, java-native-interface, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to convert a valid C JNI binding to C++ because I want to link to C++ source (open source implementation of an image processing algorithm) from some Java code. I got everything working in C, this includes the Java class, the C version of the JNI binding and the build system and **excludes** using the C++ source.

I am now trying to convert the JNI binding to C++ so I can add the C++ source to the build system and call it from the binding, but I'm running into an undefined symbol.

My Makefile is pretty straightforward:

```
GCC = gcc -Wall -g -std=gnu99
CXX = g++ -Wall -g
LIBOBJS = parallelsurf_jni.o

LIB=libparallelsurf.so
DESTLIB=../../lib/$(LIB)

all: $(DESTLIB)


$(DESTLIB): $(LIB)
    cp $(LIB) $(DESTLIB)

libparallelsurf.so: parallelsurf_ParallelSURF.h $(LIBOBJS)
    ld --shared $(LIBOBJS) -o libparallelsurf.so 

parallelsurf_ParallelSURF.h:
    echo "Rebuilding JNI headers. Ensure java file has been recently built."
    javah -classpath ../../parallelsurf.jar -jni parallelsurf.ParallelSURF

clean:
    rm -f $(LIBOBJS) *~ parallelsurf_ParallelSURF.h $(LIB) $(DESTLIB) $(LIBOBJS)

JNI_INCLUDES = -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -shared -O2 -c -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -D_REENTRANT $< $(JNI_INCLUDES)
```

My header file is thus automatically generated with `javah` and I don't appear to have mangled it when copying from `.h` to `.cpp`.  I do not have `extern "C"` blocks in the .cpp file, as guided by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827299/c-code-compiled-with-c-undefined-reference).

I also included a pragma as guided by this post: [Undefined Symbol _gxx_personality_v0 on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203548/undefined-symbol-gxx-personality-v0-on-link). The pragma is `#pragma GCC java_exceptions`

Now, that undefined symbol (gxx_personality) seems to be well referenced/documented on the web. A number of posts point to this comment on [C++/Java exception handling](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/Exception-Handling.html), which suggests using that pragma. However, after including that pragma, I get another undefined symbol that is not well covered (I get exactly 1 Google hit): `_gcj_personality_v0`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/chardson/chardson/parallelsurf/lib/libparallelsurf.so: /home/chardson/chardson/parallelsurf/lib/libparallelsurf.so: undefined symbol: __gcj_personality_v0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at parallelsurf.ParallelSURF.<clinit>(ParallelSURF.java:17)
    at testpsurf.<init>(testpsurf.java:11)
    at testpsurf.main(testpsurf.java:23)
```

I'm not sure what to make of this undefined symbol, and I have no idea where else to turn.  Perhaps there's just a mistake in my JNI code that could be fixed to get rid of this problem?  My JNI C++ code is included below for completeness.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#pragma GCC java_exceptions

/*
 * Class:     parallelsurf_ParallelSURF
 * Method:    parallelsurf_get_keypoints
 * Signature: (II[FZ)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_parallelsurf_ParallelSURF_parallelsurf_1get_1keypoints
  (JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jint width, jint height, jfloatArray gray, jboolean rotInvariant)
{
    // init arraylist class
    jclass arrayListClass = jenv->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
    assert(arrayListClass != NULL);

    jmethodID alInitMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "<init>", "()V");
    assert(alInitMethodId != NULL);

    jobject arrayList = jenv->NewObject(arrayListClass, alInitMethodId);

    jmethodID alAddMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
    assert(alAddMethodId != NULL);

    // init keypoint class
    jclass keypointClass = jenv->FindClass("parallelsurf/Keypoint");
    assert(keypointClass != NULL);

    jmethodID kpInitMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(keypointClass, "<init>", "(DDDDID[D)V");
    assert(kpInitMethodId != NULL);

    jdoubleArray descriptor = jenv->NewDoubleArray(10);
    assert(descriptor != NULL);

    jdouble vals[10];
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        vals[i] = (jdouble) i;
    }

    jenv->SetDoubleArrayRegion(descriptor, 0, 10, vals);

    // create keypoint
    jobject kp = jenv->NewObject(keypointClass, kpInitMethodId,
                                    (jdouble) 1, (jdouble) 2, (jdouble) 3,
                                    (jdouble) 4, (jint) 5, (jdouble) 6,
                                    descriptor);

    // add to arraylist
    jenv->CallBooleanMethod(arrayList, alAddMethodId, kp);
    jenv->DeleteLocalRef(kp);

    return arrayList;
}
```

Thanks for looking. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I should note that the working C code can be got by using the GCC compiler command listed in the makefile and changing the `%.cpp` to `%.c`, changing the file from `.cpp` to `.c`, removing the pragma, and making the usual JNI change: replace `jenv->Function(args)` with `(*jenv)->Function(jenv, args)`

Comment: As additional information, I did see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950635/how-to-compile-dynamic-library-for-a-jni-application-on-linux), which claims I should separate the C and C++ code. I'm going to see if I can't make that work, though it's certainly less clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fine gentleman on the gcc-help mailing list figured this one out:

- Instead of `#pragma GCC java_exceptions` to deal with __gxx_personality_v0, make `ld` link in `-l gcc_s`
- If __gcj_personality_v0 is undefined, make `ld` link in `-l gcj`
- Have `ld` link `-l stdc++`
- Ensure that you have libstdc++, libgcjX-dev (X is a version) and libgcc on your machine

If you're linking with g++ (I'm not), some of these may happen automatically (stdc++?)

Also, make sure you didn't forget (or lose) the `#import` line for the JNI header -- you'll need the `extern C {}` bits, or you'll get an UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: Actually, in the end I dropped `ld` and used `g++` for linking. e.g. `g++ --shared $(LIBOBJS) -o libparallelsurf.so`